# Howcan I fix TypeError: _s is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to authenticate users on a website I'm creating using firebase authentication in a react project but right now whenever I save my work there are no errors in the terminal but nothing renders in the browser instead, I get this error

**TypeError: _s is not a function**

This is my SignUp component

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Card, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/authContext';

export default function SignUp() {
    const emailRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
    


    return (
        <Container className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
        style={{ minHeight: '100vh'}}>
            <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: '400px'}}>
                <>
                    <Card>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign up</h2>
                            <Form>
                                <Form.Group id="email">
                                    <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required></Form.Control>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group id="password">
                                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required></Form.Control>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
                                    <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef} required></Form.Control>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Button className="w-100" type="submit">Sign Up</Button>
                            </Form>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
                        Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
                    </div>
                </>
            </div>     
       </Container>
    )
}
```

This is the component where I handle authentication

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()

    function Signup(email, password) {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
        })

        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    


    const value = {
        currentUser,
        Signup
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And this is my component containing my firebase api keys

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
});


export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong yet. I need some assistance, please.

Comment: Does it just error immediately when you load this component? I don't see any obvious problems at first glance. Could you try just commenting out different parts of the code until the error no longer appears? That way you can maybe isolate what is causing the issue. On a side note, you definitely want to convert your `SignUp` function and `value` object into a `useCallback` and `useMemo` respectively. Otherwise every time AuthProvider triggers it's going to make everything reading its context value re-render as well, as that value object will get recreated.

Comment: I actually tried this before posting this question and I discovered that whenever I comment out the import of { auth } from firebase in my authentication component, the component renders properly in the browser but once I uncomment it, it shows complied in the terminal but in the browser it gives the error I mentioned